# Converting SQL Query into Linq (c#) with Distinct

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to write my SQL Statement with Linq, but I don't quite get it. I know there are many familiar posts, but maybe you can help me with mine and help me to understand how it works.

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cou.Country1) AS Laender, COUNT(cou.Country1) AS Anzahl FROM SEC_User be
INNER JOIN PAR_Company com ON com.CompanyID = be.CompanyID
INNER JOIN DAT_Country cou ON cou.CountryID = com.CountryID
Group by cou.Country1
```

I think my start might be right:

```
var query = from user in db.SEC_User
join com in db.PAR_Company on user.CompanyID equals com.CompanyID
join cou in db.DAT_Country on com.CountryID equals cou.CountryID
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT cou.Country1 AS Laender, ...` to make code clearer. However...

Comment: ...(contd.) You rarely never need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` when you do `GROUP BY,` since the `GROUP BY` itself returns no duplicate rows. Simply do a plain `SELECT`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this. you don't need `DISTINCT` with group by. group by makes already it distinct.

```
var query = from user in db.SEC_User
join com in db.PAR_Company on user.CompanyID equals com.CompanyID
join cou in db.DAT_Country on com.CountryID equals cou.CountryID
group cou by user.Country1 into g
select new { Laender = g.Key, Anzahl = g.Count()};
```

Comment: Hi Serkan, thanks a lot for your answer, it worked!